# Swift - How to Network disable on Unit Test

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing

Is there any way to close Internet Connection for Unit Test? I have to check async function when the device on online or not. How can I do that ?

I know the Additional tools Package but I want to write this feature with programmatically.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Shut down the router :) Or use 3rd party libraries like https://github.com/kylef/Mockingjay

Answer (score -1):

This is how I mock an API call. The steps requires

1) No internet connection

2) Mocking the API Call and data

I have created data models for the api response and this is how I am mocking it

```
func buildActivityList() -> ActivityResponse {
    let resp = ActivityResponse(json: .null)
    let userHistory = ActivityUserHistory(json: .null)
    userHistory.time = "2018-02-16T07:41:54.046Z"
    resp.userHistory = [userHistory]
    //Add all other relevant data
    return resp
}
```

Next you need to override the function were you are calling API and pass the above mocked data as API response.

Suppose you have a class where you call the api

```
class UserService {
    func getUserDetails(completion: (_: ActivityResponse?, _: Error?)) {
        //get RESPONSE from server
        let data = ActivityResponse(object: RESPONSE)
        return completion(data, nil)
    }
}
```

Now in your test class call the `buildActivityList()` which we created and pass it in the mock class.

```
class MockUserService: UserService {
    override func getUserDetails(completion: (_: ActivityResponse?, _: Error?)) {
        return completion(buildActivityList(), nil)
    }
}
```

This way whenever you test an API call, the mock data will be injected. Thus no need for internet connection.

Hope this helps